# Please don't auto-subscribe me to job alerts

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I got an email today:

[image]

I haven't had one of those emails since I last unsubscribed from them a Long Time Ago. Today, apparently I'm subscribed to them again, despite not having done anything to that effect:

[image]

Not only do I not have any job alerts as the email would like to suggest, I also didn't switch the generic alerts to Daily, nor did I want it to be done for me.

I don't tend to keep on top of Jobs, so I don't know if this is a new type of alert email or not. If it is: **don't automatically subscribe me to things I didn't ask for.** If it isn't, why has this happened?

Comment: We never automatically subscribe you to anything. Digging into the history of this now

Comment: @DeanWard Looks like the last time I got these was on the 1st and 9th of November last year. I can't find any others in spam or deleted.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I've looked at the alert in question and it was created in April last year from an IP address used by your account. We've sent only 3 emails to you, 1 of which was today, the previous 2 (as you mention in comments) were sent in November.

I can see from the traffic logs in April that you poked around /jobs a little and the alert was created after visiting a company page. You unsubscribed from that alert but then resubscribed to it later. Happy to go into more detail, but looks like this was an alert created some time ago that was only triggered when jobs matched the search terms specified within it.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I can't say I remember doing that, but I'm not about to find out what happened there several months later.

Comment: I'm still a little suspicious. I also received an email today having not had one for months. Are you sure there hasn't been something a little screwy going on today?

Comment: @DavidG I can see that you subscribed to (funnily enough) *exactly* the same alert as ArtOfCode on 2018-12-23 at around 15:02 UTC, again, from an IP address associated with your account. That particular alert hasn't had any jobs appear for it until jobs were posted yesterday.

Comment: Ha, after I posted this, I did a bit of digging and I did wonder if that was going to be the answer. I must admit, the UI (was on my mobile at the time) doesn't lend itself very well to showing me those alerts.

Comment: @DavidG aye, it can be difficult to find in mobile; you have to go from "Email Settings" and then click the "Manage" button in the job alerts section. In the coming months we think mobile views probably go away and will be replaced with responsive views instead, but the user profile needs *a lot* of work to make that happen!

Comment: [denvercoder9, when did you subscribe to jobs?!?](https://xkcd.com/979/)